# I can not proceed to my room menu using photon in unity when i use PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom()

Tags: unity, photon

I have a TextMeshProUGUI called `EnterRoomName` and I am trying to enter the name of the room that I'm supposed to enter, but it's not working.

This is my function:

```csharp
public void JoinRoom() 
{
     PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(EnterRoomName .text);

     MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I think you'll need to provide a little more information for people to be able to help. Like any exceptions (if there) or what did you expect to happen, what is the value of `EnterRoomName.text`, etc.

Comment: Hi! @D.Kallan thanks for the reply... Actually there are no errors occur but when i click the enter room after i enter the room name its not going to my room menu on which all my players are list on that specific menu . This operation is kinda same as the Among Us on which the player need  to enter to enter that specifc room...